# Is there a way to trigger a BlocListener to listen to all changes just after its initialization?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

I need to run the listener once the page opens and listen to all changes from loading to the main emit, i followed this question [Is there a way to trigger a BlocListener just after its initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73224056/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-a-bloclistener-just-after-its-initialization)

I do cascade operation in the Blocprovider and it works fine with only the last state, the change in state is so fast that the value will change before the listener is connected so even this will not work unless you add an unnecessary Future.delayed which I don't need it all, so how the bloclistner listen to all changes and emits not only the last one once the page opens

here is how I call the bloc:

```
  case Routes.mainRoute:
        // ---- Main Screen
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider(
                  create: (BuildContext context) => AddressCubit(
                        AddressRepository(addressApi: AddressApi()),
                      )..getCurrentLocation()),
            ],
            child: const OnMapScreen(),
          ),
        );
```

and here is my cubit

```
void getCurrentLocation({double? lat, double? long}) async {

    emit(GetCureentLocationLoadedState());

   bool serviceEnabled;
   LocationPermission permission;

  serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    emit(ServiceNotEnabledState(
        message: "You need to enable location from your mobile"));
  }

  permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

  if (permission == LocationPermission.always ||
      permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse) {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
        position.latitude, position.longitude);

    emit(LocationSuccessCase());
  }
```

}

and here is my UI

```
BlocConsumer<AddressCubit, AddressState>(
              listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is GetCureentLocationLoadedState) {
             
              );
            } else if (state is ServiceNotEnabledState) {
              
            } else if (state is LocationSuccessCase) {
           
            } else {
           
            }
          }, builder: (context, state) {
            return GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal,
                               markers: markers.toSet(),
              initialCameraPosition: _openedLocation,
              onTap: (LatLng latlng) async {
                addressCubit!.getCurrentLocation(
                  lat: latlng.latitude,
                  long: latlng.longitude,
                );
                setState(() {});
              },
              onMapCreated: (mapConroller) {
                context.read<AddressCubit>().getCurrentLocation();
                gmc = mapConroller;
              },
            );
          }),
        ),
```

the bloclistner listen to only the last emit which is LocationSuccessCase, not GetCureentLocationLoadedState firstly

Comment: where and how do you create bloc?
but firstly REMOVE setState, BlocConsumer will rebuild you widget on state changed.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It just seems that the BLoC is initialized somewhere else, and as expected, the business logic is not coupled with the widgets and therefore the widget may be inserted in the widgets tree after that state change.

Comment: @VladyslavUlianytskyi i call the bloc by blocprovider in the app route, I have edited my question to include it

Comment: as i said in my question, the bloclistner listen to only the last emit which is LocationSuccessCase, not GetCureentLocationLoadedState firstly, but I need to listen to every emit not only the last one, I guess it is doing that because the change in state is so fast that the value will change before the listener is connected so even this will not work unless you add an unnecessary Future.delayed which I don't need it all, so how the bloclistner listen to all changes and emits not only the last one once the page opens @pcba-dev

Comment: This is not possible with BLoC, since it is just a `stream` and always returns the last "state" value. What you are looking for is called "[Replay Subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject)", which in not part of BLoC but you could implement a version of it with the corresponding [Dart library](https://pub.dev/packages/rx).